# Render result and viewport render are different - Cycles(3.4.0)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, error, settings

I am using the Cycles render engine for this one - Blender(3.4.0).

That is not an HDRI, but an image imported as plane with the image texture as it's Emission colour with the Emission Strength set to 10.

Viewport vs Render
[image]

Here you can see how both the images are different from each other, the grass near the tee in the viewport is a bit blurrier and has darker shadows than the rendered result, and see how the grass in the rendered result is sharp and have fewer shadows. I'd like the Render Result to look exactly like the Viewport.

[image: Outliner]

Here in the outliner, you can see that any object that has been turned off for the viewport has also been turned off for the render.

The sampling setting for the viewport and the rendered result is the same, and so are the camera settings. I've turned on 'Depth of Field' with F-Stop=7.

[image: Advanced Settings]

I have a feeling that the sampling pattern is affecting the rendered result, but what do I know?

[image: Light Bounces]

Someone suggested me to change the 'Max Bounces' settings, but I don't know what to change and how much... are the values for render and viewport 'Max Bounces' different? If yes, can you please share those values with me?

[image: Compositor]

And no, I haven't done anything in the compositor.

[image]

These are some settings that I believe that might've affected the rendered result, if you concur... please tell me what should I change so that the Rendered Result looks exactly like the Viewport.

[image: GScatter]

Also, I'm using Graswald's GScatter Blender addon to scatter the grass using Geometry Nodes and a weight mask. Could this affect the Rendered Result too?

Comment: Sorry I don't see a difference ...

Comment: @vklidu Notice how the grass near the tee is too sharp like there are perfectly straight lines... but the same grass in the viewport is a bit darker and has shadows and is a bit blurrier which helps it to bend in with rest of the scene...

Comment: I had to add both images above each other to see it. Right, there are differences (clearly identified by [blending them by difference](https://imgur.com/HEp3pqs). I'm not sure if you can get identical result. Viewport is designed to be realtime as much as possible, so there can be "small" nuances, that differs like DOF. The same for grass there can be simplification. Hm, few blades are missing in render. Also in the viewport I see more glossiness on blades, but it can be thanks to simplified model used in viewport (this could be also reason why it looks darker - its thicker).

Comment: @vklidu Now that you mention that the render has less grass than the viewport, I see it. What can be causing it? I'm using Graswald's GScatter Blender addon, if you're familiar with please do share some insights. When I added the grass, I chose 'Level of Detail' and 'Material Quality' both to be low, that might be the reason.

Comment: @vklidu Hey! I used the High option for both 'Level of Detail' and  'Material Quality'... and VOILA! it was magically cured. Apparently, those options were for rendering, the simplified model was used for rendering not the viewport, crazy... right? Anyway, much thanks to you! Ciao...